# Arrange complex datatype for fast partial match comparison

Tags: java, data-structures, dataset, abstract-data-type

I am writing a java program that compares two datasets, each set contains data of the same type. The datatypes are basically classes, containing both Strings, ints and a String[]. Let's call this class `Foo` and the datasets `a` and `b`. For each item in `a`, I need to find the item in `b` that matches it most closely.

My problem is speed - I have outlined below, in pseudo-code, what I do right now. As you can imagine, it doesn't scale very well with increasing size (and I DO have much increasing sizes...). If anyone could point me in the direction of a better solution, I would greatly appreciate it. I am aware that sorting the arrays, in case of e.g. String or int comparisons, would increase speed vastly, but since my datatype is more complex, I don't see how that could work here.

```
Foo[] a = new Foo[...];
Foo[] b = new Foo[...];
for (item_a : a) {
   double bestMatch = 0;
   for (item_b : b) {
      double match = compareFoo(item_a,item_b);
      if (match > bestMatch) {
          bestMatch = match;
      }
   }
   //Do stuff with bestMatch - display, save etc.
}

private double compareFoo(Foo item_a, Foo item_b) {
   //Compare every element of a and b, 
   //return value between 0 (no match) and 1 (identical)
}
```

Comment: You `compareFoo()` logic is unclear. And the comments seem to be misleading.  It should calculate the *distance* between `item_a` and `item_b`, shouldn't it?.   Also is `comapreFoo(a, b)` equal to `compareFoo(b, a)`?

Comment: The logic behind `compareFoo()` is irrelevant in this case, as the execution time of the function is static. That's why I left it out. And yes, the order of arguments for `compareFoo()` doesn't matter.

Comment: I do not need the actual code, I need to know whether it indeed compares "*every element of a and b*".

Comment: Right, I edited it slightly, so the arguments of `compareFoo()` are now called `item_a` and `item_b` - I can see how that was a little misleading before. The function merely compares two items.

The item-by-item comparison is done in the two for-loops in the main function.

Comment: Are you sure you could not come up with some kind of arbitrary ordering so that when you sort your arrays with it the second loop never takes too long to find the match?

Comment: If you are going to increase performance somewhere it is in the specifics of how the comparison is done. What I mean by this is that by exploiting whatever specific characteristics in this comparison you might be able to avoid looping through the whole ´b´ every time. In other words, you need to stop doing an exhaustive search on ´b´ for every ´a´.

Comment: I thought about doing that, and I could in the cases where I get a similarity of 1, but that would be rare cases. Still worth trying though.